# upload video to youtube from updated Xcode app

Tags: ios, xcode, video, youtube, oauth-2.0

I have an app that I used to be able to sign into google account and then upload a video to that account.  However the apps bundle ID changed and I had to update to googleSignIn.
So now when I open the view controller I want to upload the video from I have a google Sign In button which the user taps and signs in and choose to let the app have access to scopes:

```
googleapis.com/auth/youtube
googleapis.com/auth/youtube.upload
googleapis.com/auth/youtubepartner
googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl
```

I also update the apps developers key
So I now have a developers Key and a client id that I replaced from the old ones in the app for the following code

```
- (GTMOAuth2Authentication *)authForDailyMotion {
NSURL *url = [GDataServiceGoogleYouTube youTubeUploadURLForUserID:kGDataServiceDefaultUser];
NSString *redirectURI = @"http://www.google.com/OAuthCallback";
NSString *clientID = @"552XXXXXXXX3-banchtj9877k4o4noj32eu1h5jokctu0.apps.googleusercontent.com";
NSString *clientSecret = devKey;
GTMOAuth2Authentication *auth;
auth = [GTMOAuth2Authentication authenticationWithServiceProvider:@"my little world"
                                                         tokenURL:url
                                                      redirectURI:redirectURI
                                                         clientID:clientID
                                                     clientSecret:clientSecret];
return auth;
```

}

After the user signs in to google they are taken to a page that shows the access the app is requesting access to

manage the youtube account
view and manage assets and associated content on Youtube
manage youtube videos

When the user currently taps the "allow" button they are taken to google.com where they can upload the video and other things from the camera roll on the device.
I want the user to be redirected back to a view within the app where the viewer can 
put in a title, description, tags, choose a category, and choose its privacy and then publish the video directly from the app using

```
- (void)uploadVideoFile {
NSString *audioName = [pictureDictionary4 objectForKey:@"photoVideokey"];
NSArray *pathsa = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectorya = [pathsa objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *moviePath = [documentsDirectorya stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/Movie"];
//Get a full path to the image in the documents directory.
NSString *fullPatha = [moviePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:audioName];
GDataServiceGoogleYouTube *service = [self youTubeService];
NSURL *url = [GDataServiceGoogleYouTube youTubeUploadURLForUserID:kGDataServiceDefaultUser];
NSString *filename = audioName;
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:fullPatha];
GDataYouTubeMediaGroup *media = [GDataYouTubeMediaGroup mediaGroup];
[media setMediaTitle:title];
[media setMediaDescription:desc];
[media addMediaCategory:category];
[media setMediaKeywords:keywords];
NSString *mimeType = [GDataUtilities MIMETypeForFileAtPath:fullPatha
                                           defaultMIMEType:@"video/mp4"];
 GDataEntryYouTubeUpload *entry;
entry = [GDataEntryYouTubeUpload uploadEntryWithMediaGroup:media
                                                /*fileHandle:fileHandle*/
                                                      data:data
                                                  MIMEType:mimeType
                                                      slug:filename];
GDataServiceTicket *ticket;
ticket = [service fetchEntryByInsertingEntry:entry
                                  forFeedURL:url
                                    delegate:self
                              didFinishSelector:@selector(uploadTicket:finishedWithEntry:error:)];


[self setUploadTicket:ticket];
GTMHTTPUploadFetcher *uploadFetcher = (GTMHTTPUploadFetcher *)[ticket objectFetcher];
[uploadFetcher setLocationChangeBlock:^(NSURL *url) {
    [self setUploadLocationURL:url];
```

by tapping "publish"

I think the redirect url needs to be changed so the authentication is given to the app and then used to upload the video.  However I am not sure about this

Now if the user taps the done button and goes back to the app and puts in the information described above and taps "publish"

I get the following error.

```
upload failed: Error Domain=com.google.HTTPStatusCode=401 *(User authentacation required)
```

I think this is because the authorization is only given to do the upload on line and not through the app.

Can someone tell me if I am correct in this assumption and is so how can I redirect the user back to the app to upload the video after tapping "allow"

and if I am incorrect in my assumption can someone give me some guidance on how to make this work as I want, please.

Answer (score 0):

1. Follow [this](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/sign-in?ver=swift) steps to get GoogleSignIn.
2. Here is [API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert) to upload a video to YouTube.